# only print grep match itself, neither other things on the line nor additional line breaks

Tags: bash, shell, grep

When we use `grep foobar` it prints all lines that contain `foobar` entirely, not just the foobar parts

```
$ echo "abc foobar uvw foobar xyz" | grep foobar
abc foobar uvw foobar xyz
```

On the other hand, if we use the `-o` flag, it does not print the other parts of the line.
However, now it inserts additional line breaks:

```
$ echo "abc foobar uvw foobar xyz" | grep foobar
foobar
foobar
```

The output has two lines despite the input having only one line.

How can we get the output `foobarfoobar` ? (If matches are on different lines, I would still like a line break between them)

Comment: I don't think this can be done with grep, it's easy with perl or awk

Comment: add `-n` option to get the matched line numbers and merge output for the same line numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an awk solution:

```
awk -F 'foobar' 'NF>1{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf "%s", FS; print ""}' file

foobarfoobar
foobar
foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar
foobar
```

As per comments below if requirement is to use regex then following `gnu awk` command can be used:

```
awk -v RS='foo[a-z]+' 'RT{s=RT; r=NR>1 && ($0~/\n/)}
      s{printf "%s%s", (r?ORS:""), s; s=""} END{print ""}' file
```

Where input is:

```
cat file

abc foobar uvw foobar xyz
abc foobar 123
abc 123
foobar foobar foobar foobar
foobar
```

Comment: Nice, much better than my attempt (which I'm about to delete!).

Comment: @anubhava This will print blank lines for none matching lines though which OP commented on my answer saying they did not want.

Comment: Both commands in my answer won't print blank lines when pattern isn't present. (I removed my earlier comment)

Comment: @anubhava They won't now that you have changed them, no. But your RS command will not work as you think.Try it with the data from my regex example in my question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I refined my gnu awk command further.

Comment: Yesterday, I already used the perl version. It took 45 min to complete (14 GB file). Although, on a 17 MB test file, perl takes 2.5 s, and this awk solution takes 1s, so it seems awk was more suited. Although the awk had a weird regex flavor, I had to replace `.*` with `[\n]*` and it warns about `\[`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems I actually had to solve a different problem with duplicates removed

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment about duplicate removal.

Answer (score 3):

You could use perl

```
perl -lne 'print /foobar/g if /foobar/' file
```

#### Example

Input

```
foobar 12 c fds f foobar
wak foobar sshak
dsfgsg dsfgsgf sdgfsfd
foobar foobar foobar
```

output

```
foobarfoobar
foobar
foobarfoobarfoobar
```

#### Example with regex

```
perl -lne 'print /foo[a-z]+/g if /foo[a-z]+/' file
```

Input

```
foobuz 12 c fds f foobaz
wak foocuz sshak
sdfsdf ds fdf
fooduz foofuz fooguz
```

output

```
foobuzfoobaz
foocuz
fooduzfoofuzfooguz
```

Comment: Can we get an output without empty lines where no matches are? I was thinking of the normal grep output, just with no matches removed

Comment: @BeniBela Updated for that requirement.